# VirtualBox error when trying to run Ubuntu "Failed to open a session"

Tags: virtualbox

Im trying to run Ubuntu in a virtual machine on virtual box. So far I have reinstalled virtualbox once to see if it was the cause, then I redownloaded the .iso, but when I try to run the machine it says it still won't run.

Failed to open a session for the virtual machine ubuntu.

The virtual machine 'ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}

Comment: I had this problem tonight and I fixed it. I've been searching Stackoverflow for people who may have similar problems. Check out my answer about the [vboxdrv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718480/1116861) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't power off the vm after last run, try right-click on VirtualBox Manager >> Discard Saved State. This will start the vm from (virtual) power off state. Current state of vm will be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using VirtualBox 4.3.14? There's a known bug which could be related: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13187

I was having this problem, downgrading "solved" it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did and it worked properly:

(1) Move/copy your hard disk image (`my_old_vm.vdi`) to a 
    convenient folder, e.g. `C:\my\VMS\my_new_vm\`

(2) Create a new virtual machine (click the new button).

(2.b) At some point in time you are asked about the disk 
      to be used; choose 'existing disk image' and browse
      to where you moved `my_old_vm.vdi` and select that.

(3) Start the VM and reconfigure the machine settings.

(4) Possibly delete the old machine. If you did not move the
    `.vdi` file, then do not delete all files related to the 
    old machine.

This saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

For me "Detachable Start" works, can you try it out?

Answer (score 0):

I just went through exactly the same problem on a Windows VM. Uninstalling the Norton Internet Security and restarting my computer solved the problem. Credit to this article that I found here: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=62615