# Oracle Virtual Box error: failure to open a session with Hortonworks

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I've researched the questions already on stackoverflow that suggest upgrading to the most recent version of Virtual Box; one question at the time suggested upgrading to V4.3.14.  Well, I'm on V 4.3.20.  I've reinstalled about 5 times, and ensured the BIOS was set to virtualization.

I continue to get the error message below.

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Hortonworks Sandbox with HDP 2.2.

The virtual machine 'Hortonworks Sandbox with HDP 2.2' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).  More details may be available in 'C:\Users\559048\VirtualBox VMs\Hortonworks Sandbox with HDP 2.2\Logs\VBoxStartup.log'.

Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

It is currently installed on my work laptop, so I installed it on mh personal (Windows) PC.  On my personal PC it starts perfectly.  Is this an antivirus issue?

Comment: Maybe. Have you seen [this topic on the VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=64777)?

Answer (score 0):

Does the log referenced point to anything having to do with the vboxdrv driver? If so, I just figured it out and posted the answer on a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718229/1116861).

Another check you can do is from the command line type `sc.exe query vboxdrv`. If that shows stopped you can try and manually start it by typing `sc.exe start vboxdrv`. If that command fails because the file is not found then head on over to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27718229/1116861) and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I chose 'detachable start' instead of 'normal start', it worked well for me.